# Reset VS 2012 Windows Simulator settings

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I was playing with the simulator that comes with VS 2012 and decided to crank up the resolution to see if my app would look well in high resolutions. Little did I realize how much that would demand from my machine. The simulator crashed and I haven't been able to use it since. I can start it outside of visual studio but as soon as I click anything it freezes and starts to lock up my machine. I'm running Windows 8 in a virtual machine so it's already a bit resource limited.

Is there a way (either through the registry or some other means) to reset the simulator settings?  I need to turn the resolution back down so I can actually use it to test my apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely less than optimal, but I found a solution if you are desperate. I decided to repair VS 2012 to solve some other things and it seems to have reset the simulator settings.

This just further confirms that there has to be a simple way to do this because the installer probably just copied default registry settings in place with fresh copies of the files. Therefore I'm not going to accept this answer for at time so that others can see this and hopefully offer a better answer.